# How do i merge (i.e 'concat') 100+ .csv files using the pandas module?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I'm a newbie to data science with python. So, I wanted to play around with the following data "https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/limits.html." The main problem here is that instead of giving me one file containing the data for all years, it contains a separate file for each year. Furthermore, each separate file also lacks column headings.

FYI, the data contains the names, genders and some identification number of all registered US citizens from 1910 onwards. The data is available to the public (intended to aid demographers tracking trends in popular names).

Thus, one major problem I'm facing is the need to edit more than 100 files directly (manually, open each and edit) so as to ensure that all column headings are the same (which is required for a function like concat to work).

Another big problem is the sheer magnitude of the task. It's very, very inefficient to use concat for 100* files, as well as use up more than 100 lines of code in just scanning/reading your data

Of course, 'concat' was built for this, but I think it's quite inefficient to use it for around 130 files. Regarding the missing column headings, I've manually edited some files, but there are just too many to be edited directly.

```
names2010 = pd.read_csv("../yob2010.txt")
names2011 = pd.read_csv("../yob2011.txt")
names = pd.concat([names2010, names2011])
```

intuitively, this is what I want to avoid>

```
#rough notation 
names = pd.concat([names1910, names1911 ..., names2017, names2018])
```

this is just for two years' worth of data. I need to create a single data frame consisting of all data from the years 1910 to 2018.

update: I've figured out how to combine all different .txt files, but still need to resolve for column headings.

```
dataframes = pd.read_csv("../yob1910.txt")
for year in range(1911, 2019):
       temp_frame = pd.read_csv("../yob{}.txt".format(year))
       dataframes = pd.concat([temp_frame, dataframes])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'../' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

list = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow - and data science! It seems you may be early enough in the learning curve not to have experimented with Python's native structures - the container data types. They can be amazingly helpful in simplifying your code by looping.

One simple way to make the task easier is to keep each dataset as a item in a list. For example (this code is untested):

```
dataframes = []
for year in range(1910, 2018):
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(f"../yob{year}.txt"))
names = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Note that the filenames are constructed from the year, using Python 3.6's f-string feature, but you could replace that with other ways to achieve the same result should you be working with and earlier version. Two alternatives:

```
"../yob{}.txt".format(year)
```

and

```
"../yob%d.txt" % year
```

Comment: Figured out the 'concat' part. Your code isn't working because dataframes is a list, and for some reason, pandas does not support the elements of a list being joined together, even if they're data frames. However, based on your solution, I was able to implement the algorithm. Instead of initialising dataframes to an empty list, initialise it to the 1910 file. Thus, every time the loop is executed, we can join the file with data frames using the 'concat' function as follows. The code is as follows:

Comment: I've updated the code above, still need t figure out the column headings part.